# Retrieve data the user added to a table

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

In a VueJS application I have a `button` and a `table`: when I click the button, I dynamically create a new `row` in a table.

Every table row has 4 cells: I populate any `cell` with text and I add a `select` inside one of them, so that this is the final result:

```
<tr>
 <td>text 1</td>
 <td>text 2</td>
 <td>text 3</td>
 <td><select><option ...>...</option>...</select></td>
</tr>
```

At some point the user (when he has finished adding/removing items to/from this table) must click a button and **send the data contained in the table** to a server.

So, he must retrieve the content of text nodes and the various options selected by the user (or, I don't know, something stores somewhere the current content of the rows).

So, using Vue, how do I retrieve all the data the user should send? (I must say right now I store the content of any row as an `Object` in an array, but I can't figure out how to store the options selected by the user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to separate your inputs and your saved data. I usually use a `placholder` to do the trick. So when I need to send anything, in this case, an array, I can just retrieve it right away.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    placeholder: {
      prop1: '',
      prop2: '',
      prop3: '',
      prop4: ''
    },
    items: [
      {
        prop1: 'A',
        prop2: 'B',
        prop3: 'C',
        prop4: 'Yes'
      },
      {
        prop1: 'D',
        prop2: 'E',
        prop3: 'F',
        prop4: 'No'
      },
      {
        prop1: 'G',
        prop2: 'H',
        prop3: 'I',
        prop4: 'Yes'
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    addItem() { 
      this.items.push(this.placeholder)
      this.placeholder = {
        prop1: '',
        prop2: '',
        prop3: '',
        prop4: ''
      }
    },
    sendResult() { console.log(this.items) }
  }
})
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Text 1</th>
        <th>Text 2</th>
        <th>Text 3</th>
        <th>Selection</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="item in items">
        <td>{{item.prop1}}</td>
        <td>{{item.prop2}}</td>
        <td>{{item.prop3}}</td>
        <td>
          <select v-model="item.prop4">
            <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
            <option>Yes</option>
            <option>No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" v-model="placeholder.prop1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" v-model="placeholder.prop2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" v-model="placeholder.prop3" /></td>
        <td>
          <select v-model="placeholder.prop4">
            <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
            <option>Yes</option>
            <option>No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button v-on:click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
    <button v-on:click="sendResult()">Send Result</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a separate rows array of objects. What I didn't know was how to alter one of the objects field: in particular, the user can change the value of the select before data is sent (so, to reflect this change, I added a field and a v-model). Thanks for your kind reply

Comment: So the user can only change the `select` option after the item is added?

Comment: Exactly (but can add many rows, of course). In the real app, there are two different selects, but I only needed to understand how one worked   :-)

Comment: @3000 just modified the solution, the change is really simple, just replace the select field with a well... `select`